# Mod-rewrite : Force SSL & remove extension - 50% success on same scenario

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, server

I am having some very weird issues with my .htaccess rewrites.

For 2 of the 4 pages I have tested , the rewrites work , the other two fail for some reason and redirect to the main page (as expected of my error rewrite)

The tests I am doing are making sure all files with .html have their extensions removed as well as ensuring a https connection.

I test them individually and as a pair (rewrite/redirect to https as well as remove .html). They only fail when I try to rewrite both conditions

Sample URL:

> http://www.websitename.co/about.html

Expected:

> https://www.websitename.co/about

Works for "index.html" , but not "about.html" for example.
All pages are simple, one-word-named pages , no special characters etc.

I repeated the test in the same fashion for all 4 pages , but for 2 pages , they work , for the other 2 ,they dont.

Some help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex home.html home.php index.php index.html index.htm

ErrorDocument 404 www.WEBSITENAME.co

#Force ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

#Ecwid rewrite
RewriteRule ^shop/.*$ shop [L]

#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Add `L`-flag to the 1st rule otherwise you may get wrong redirect with the last rule. Clear browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I fixed it with the following.
I tried the [L] flag with the old code but somehow it wasnt working. Maybe my cache wasnt cleared.

```
#Force ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.WEBSITENAME.co/$1 [R,L]
```